# Something like SendToBack for TApplication

Tags: forms, delphi, z-order

Good day to all!

I want to emulate work of different forms in my app as different programms.
 
All forms have its own button on TaskBar, mainform of app is invisible and Application.ShowMainForm := false.
But if I show two forms, then open some programm that overlay both forms, then open first form (second form is behind some programm), then close first form, the second form activates and restores in front of some programm.
I understand that it restores because after closing first form my app keep active state and that's why first visible form is shown. How can I prevent restoring second form? It seems that I need send to back my app after closing, but I don't know how.

> @David Heffernan
>   It's actually Windows that is behind all of that. When one of your
>   forms is closed, Windows has to decide where to move the focus too.
>   And it chooses to move it to another top-level window in your process,
>   since a visible one exists. It makes this happen by sending the window
>   that it selects a WM_SETFOCUS message. No doubt you can intercept this
>   and stop it happening

I have tried to intercepr WM_SETFOCUS on my window, but there is no such message.

```
type
  TfMyForm = class(TForm)  
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FOldWindowProc: TWndMethod;
    procedure NewWindowProc(var Message: TMessage);
  end;

implementation

procedure TfMyForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FOldWindowProc := WindowProc;
  WindowProc := NewWindowProc;
end;

procedure TfMyForm.NewWindowProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Message.Msg = WM_SETFOCUS then
    Beep;
  FOldWindowProc(Message);
end;
```

Comment: How have you put the taskbar buttons there?

Comment: procedure TfMyForm.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
    begin
      inherited CreateParams(Params);
      Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
      Params.WndParent := 0;
    end;

Comment: Why did you use `WS_EX_APPWINDOW`? Surely `WndParent := 0` is the way to do this.

Comment: Yes, I answer in my previous comment. Sorry, I don't know how to format code in comments

Comment: I'd try `SetWindowPos(..., HWND_BOTTOM, ...)`

Comment: I mean why did you do both? `WndParent := 0` is enough. I can't help with the main question right now mind you. But I'm sure somebody else will.

Comment: Really, WndParent := 0 automatically sets WS_EX_APPWINDOW. Thanks, I will remove it.

Comment: Free Consulting, As I understand SetWindowPos will send some form (not an application) to bottom. So I have to send all my forms (there can be more than two forms) to bottom. I'll try, thanks for advice.

Comment: No, `WndParent=0` does not set `WS_EX_APPWINDOW`. But unowned windows, that is `WndParent=0`, appear in taskbar.

Comment: It's actually Windows that is behind all of that. When one of your forms is closed, Windows has to decide where to move the focus too. And it chooses to move it to another top-level window in your process, since a visible one exists. It makes this happen by sending the window that it selects a `WM_SETFOCUS` message. No doubt you can intercept this and stop it happening.

Comment: OK, the `WM_SETFOCUS` goes the active control. It's `WM_ACTIVATE` that goes to the top level window. I mis-spoke. Sorry. Actually I'm a bit lost. It's a little hard to tell which part of this is the VCL and which is Windows. If I were going to proceed I'd probably make a non VCL app that created two top level windows with WndParent equal to 0 and experiment with them, without the VCL.

Comment: You can put each form in its own dll. When Application.Handle is not assigned, forms in dlls act pretty independent.

Comment: Which window do you want to be activated. Something needs to be. What should it be?

Comment: @David Heffernan, previous programm. For example, order of visible windows is (from bottom to top) my Form1, some programm's window (iexplore or firefox or some maximized programm), my Form2. After closing Form2 previous window should be restored, not Form1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is solution I have found myself.

```
procedure SwitchToPreviousWindow(AHandle: HWND);
var PrevWindow: HWND;
begin
  PrevWindow := GetNextWindow(AHandle, GW_HWNDNEXT);
  while PrevWindow <> NULL do
  begin
    if IsWindowVisible(PrevWindow) then
    begin
      SetForegroundWindow(PrevWindow);
      Exit;
    end;
    PrevWindow := GetNextWindow(PrevWindow, GW_HWNDNEXT);
  end;
end;

procedure TfMyForm.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  SwitchToPreviousWindow(Self.Handle);
end;
```

Comment: you are a genius. ask and answer yourself.